# sql query help pivot

Tags: sql, oracle, pivot, obiee

Hey my problem goes like this , it might be usefull for other people as well 
   I have a order with a instance_id , that order has several tickets with different ticket_number as sr_num but all have same service instance id . Ticket may be in different stages as open closed or in progress, 
Suppose there are 4 tickets of an order and there are many orders with 4 or less tickets
I find all open tickets of one type of ticket , get its service_instance_id and corresponding to it , find other tickets which are open for that order .

Using following query , i can find it , but it all comes below one another , i want it for a particular order , all 4 ticket info to come in one single line , if a particular ticket is closed for that order , it should not be displayed

```
 select a.sr_num Acceptance_TT, a.act_open_dt Acceptance_Date, e.login Acceptance_Owner , c.sr_area, c.sr_num, c.act_open_dt, d.login, case when c.sr_stat_id in ('Closed','Cancelled') then '-' else c.sr_stat_id end TT_Status
    from 
    siebel.s_srv_req a -- GOC TT
    ,siebel.s_order_item b -- ServiceInstanceID
    ,siebel.s_srv_req c -- Project Management
    ,siebel.s_user d -- Owner
    ,siebel.s_user e -- GOC Owner
    where 
    a.sr_area = 'GOC Acceptance' and a.sr_num='20130601-3-28'
    and a.sr_stat_id in ('Open - GOC')
    and a.x_service_instance_id = b.row_id
    and c.x_service_instance_id = b.row_id
    and c.sr_area = 'Project Management'
    --and c.sr_stat_id not in ('Closed','Cancelled')
    and c.owner_emp_id = d.row_id
    and a.owner_emp_id = e.row_id  PM 5:39 
    UNION all
    select a.sr_num Acceptance_TT, a.act_open_dt Acceptance_Date, e.login Acceptance_Owner, c.sr_area, c.sr_num, c.act_open_dt, d.login, case when c.sr_stat_id in ('Closed','Cancelled') then '-' else c.sr_stat_id end TT_Status
    from 
    siebel.s_srv_req a -- GOC TT
    ,siebel.s_order_item b -- ServiceInstanceID
    ,siebel.s_srv_req c -- Provisioning
    ,siebel.s_user d -- Owner
    ,siebel.s_user e -- GOC Owner
    where 
    a.sr_area = 'GOC Acceptance' and a.sr_num='20130601-3-28'
    and a.sr_stat_id in ('Open - GOC')
    and a.x_service_instance_id = b.row_id
    and c.x_service_instance_id = b.row_id
    and c.sr_area = 'Provisioning'
    --and c.sr_stat_id not in ('Closed','Cancelled')
    and c.owner_emp_id = d.row_id
    and a.owner_emp_id = e.row_id  PM 5:39 
    UNION all
    select a.sr_num Acceptance_TT, a.act_open_dt Acceptance_Date, e.login Acceptance_Owner, c.sr_area, c.sr_num, c.act_open_dt, d.login, case when c.sr_stat_id in ('Closed','Cancelled') then '-' else c.sr_stat_id end TT_Status
    from 
    siebel.s_srv_req a -- GOC TT
    ,siebel.s_order_item b -- ServiceInstanceID
    ,siebel.s_srv_req c -- CE Implementation
    ,siebel.s_user d -- Owner
    ,siebel.s_user e -- GOC Owner
    where 
    a.sr_area = 'GOC Acceptance' and a.sr_num='20130601-3-28'
    and a.sr_stat_id in ('Open - GOC')
    and a.x_service_instance_id = b.row_id
    and c.x_service_instance_id = b.row_id
    and c.sr_area = 'CE Implementation'
    --and c.sr_stat_id not in ('Closed','Cancelled')
    and c.owner_emp_id = d.row_id
    and a.owner_emp_id = e.row_id
```

Comment: What is your database version? I can see that `siebel.s_srv_req.sr_area`  is the decisive factor for a particular group of tickets, how many distinct values does this column have and what are they apart from `CE Implementation`, `Provisioning` and `Project Management` ?

Comment: order no - 123  service instance id = x1
ticket_no =7    service instance id = x1   CE imple
ticket_no =8    service instance id = x1   Provisioning
ticket_no =9    service instance id = x1   PM

Comment: database version is 11g 
the coloumn has many distinct values , but m interested in only these 
ce, Pm , pro .... check a particular GOC acceptance ticket to find wheather its open , if open find status of CE, PM , PRo , else next service instance

Answer (score 1):

Try this and share the results, I do not have your configuration to test

```
with tab as (
    select a.sr_num Acceptance_TT, 
           a.act_open_dt Acceptance_Date, 
           e.login Acceptance_Owner, 
           c.sr_area, 
           c.sr_num, 
           c.act_open_dt, 
           d.login, 
           case when c.sr_stat_id in ('Closed','Cancelled') then '-' else c.sr_stat_id end TT_Status
    from 
    siebel.s_srv_req a -- GOC TT
    ,siebel.s_order_item b -- ServiceInstanceID
    ,siebel.s_srv_req c -- CE Implementation
    ,siebel.s_user d -- Owner
    ,siebel.s_user e -- GOC Owner
    where 
    a.sr_area = 'GOC Acceptance' and a.sr_num='20130601-3-28'
    and a.sr_stat_id in ('Open - GOC')
    and a.x_service_instance_id = b.row_id
    and c.x_service_instance_id = b.row_id
    and c.sr_area in ('CE Implementation', 'Project Management', 'Provisioning')
    and c.owner_emp_id = d.row_id
    and a.owner_emp_id = e.row_id
    )
 select * 
   from tab 
  pivot (min(TT_Status) as TT_Status for (sr_area) in ('CE Implementation' as CE, 'Project Management' as PM, 'Provisioning' as PRO))
```

Comment: Hey san thank you for your time and patience , That query run fine , i got the base , i can develope the query to futher suit my need , Thanks a lot SUPERMAN !